# Syntax for a repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to conduct a repeated measures ANOVA on the following data:

```
id     pre-treatment     post-treatment
1      212               208
2      192               189
3      167               168
4      151               151
5      135               128
6      105               118
7      88                88
8      67                71
9      55                50
10     27                30
```

An [online repeated measures anova calculator](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/anovarepeated/default.aspx) tells me that the p-value of the above repeated measures anova is: `0.914259`.  I agree that this is correct.

But when I try this in R, I use the following syntax:

```
model <- aov( post-treatment ~ pre-treatment + Error(id), data = df.anova )
  print(summary(model))
```

And I get the following output:

```
Error: id
    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
pre  1   1448    1448

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
pre         1 702527  702527   26248 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 217   5808      27                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

But `p < 2e-16` is a lot different from `p = 0.914259`

What gives?  I'm sure something is wrong with my syntax about how I'm running the ANOVA with the `aov` function.  There are many tutorials online about how to do repeated measures ANOVA in R.  But most of them either

- spend 15 pages explaining ANOVA and repeated-measures ANOVA like I've
  never heard of ANOVA

or they

- have a 7 or 8 page example using the    `mtcars` dataset that leave
  me unable to see the forest for the    trees.

Can anyone advise me on how to do repeated measures ANOVA in R?

Answer (score 1):

The factor is the treatment. You have to use such a dataset:

```
   id   y treatment
1   1 212       pre
2   2 192       pre
3   3 167       pre
4   4 151       pre
5   5 135       pre
6   6 105       pre
7   7  88       pre
8   8  67       pre
9   9  55       pre
10 10  27       pre
11  1 208      post
12  2 189      post
13  3 168      post
14  4 151      post
15  5 128      post
16  6 118      post
17  7  88      post
18  8  71      post
19  9  50      post
20 10  30      post
```

---

```
dat0 <- read.table(text = "id     pre     post
1      212               208
2      192               189
3      167               168
4      151               151
5      135               128
6      105               118
7      88                88
8      67                71
9      55                50
10     27                30", header = TRUE)

dat0$id <- factor(dat0$id)

dat <- rbind(
  data.frame(id = dat0$id, y = dat0$pre),
  data.frame(id = dat0$id, y = dat0$post)
)
dat$treatment <- gl(2, 10, labels = c("pre", "post"))

summary(aov(y ~ treatment + Error(id), data = dat))
```

---

```
Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
treatment  1    0.2    0.20   0.012  0.914
Residuals  9  146.8   16.31
```